# Getting the error: “No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI” in WebAPI and AngularJS

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, angular-resource

I'm very confused. I'm using ASP.NET WebApi 2 as rest api and AngularJS for the SPA. My application uses 4 rest requests. but only one doesn't work and I don't know why.

I've defined the process as follows:

Client-side:

```
//Controller
CrudService.getRepo(selFrom, selTo).$promise.then(
   function (response) {
      ...
   },
   function (err) {
      $log.error('Mth: ', err);
   });

//CrudService
function getRepo(selFrom, selTo) {
   return ResService.ds022.query(
      {
         from: selFrom,
         to: selTo
      }
   );
}

//ResService:
function ResService($resource, baseUrl) {
    return {
        ds022: $resource(baseUrl + '/api/qr_ds022/mth_test', {
            from: '@from',
            to: '@to'
        }, {})
    }
}
```

And on the other hand: Server-side (WebAPI)

```
[RoutePrefix("api/qr_ds022")]
public class QR_DS022Controller : ApiController
{
   private TestContext db = new TestContext();

   [HttpGet]
   [Route("mth_test")]
   public IQueryable<getRep_Result> getRepos(DateTime from, DateTime to)
   {
      var results = db.getRep(from, to).AsQueryable();
      return results;
   }
}
```

The Database model was created with Entity Framework 6. I have no idea where the problem is. As you can see, the route was defined correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Map route one place with function parameter, try this way

```
public class QR_DS022Controller : ApiController
{
   private TestContext db = new TestContext();

   [HttpGet]
   [Route("api/qr_ds022/mth_test/{from}/{to}")]
   public IQueryable<getRep_Result> getRepos(DateTime from, DateTime to)
   {
      var results = db.getRep(from, to).AsQueryable();
      return results;
   }
}
```

Comment: it doesn't work. In my other requests I also don't need the parameters in the route address!